# why when datagram socket buffer size is large, the drop rate is high

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, udp

I'm writing network protocol based on UDP. I faced the strange behaviour of DatagramSocket. When i'm setting large send buffer, drop rate is high, but it should be contrariwise.

Any ideas why it behave this way?

Thanks un advance!

By "*large buffer size*" i mean 16-32 Mb

My test enviorment is 1Gbit network, with high latency (240 ms roundtrip)

Comment: Can you give a little more of a description of what you mean when you say you are writing a network protocal based on UDP?

Comment: what is your test environment?

Comment: Why should it be contrarywise?

Comment: @glebreutov, I have designed this protocol over UDP in Java for high BDP, and I am able to get speed of 70 Mbps on 100 Mbps, where TCP failing to pick above 10 Mbps. You don't have to make buffers large, but you have to set some delay between sending each packets from sender..

Comment: Do you mean 16-32 Mega-bit as in `b` for bit like 1 Gb/s means 1 Gbit per second? Or do you mean 16-32 MB?  In any case, anything over 1 MB on the network in *total* I would expect to see significant drop outs.

Comment: I get 240 ms round trip latency from london to tokyo via new york. I assume you are testing worst case latency? If you are using a WAN you have a chain where the weakest link is the most utilised router between your sender and receiver.  All the routers in the chain will potentially drop some packets (and the network adapter)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I mean 16-32 MB buffers.

Comment: @PeterLawrey "? In any case, anything over 1 MB on the network in total I would expect to see significant drop outs" I can't get why large buffers causing significant drops?

Comment: @glebreutov You might be using a large buffer in your software but that doesn't change the buffer size of the hardware involved.  It has a fixed and often fairly small buffer size and when it fills for any reason momentarily, even when it has nothing to do with what you are doing, packets can get dropped.  What many banks do to solve this is buy dedicated hardware to build a dedicated network for UDP and control the traffic from the sender to the receiver.  They also make sure all the routers can easily buffer all the data sent.

Comment: @glebreutov To answer your question, the larger your send buffers are, the less likely that much data will fit into downstream buffers.  Try using packets which are closer to 512 bytes each.

Answer (score 4):

Buffers in your network adapters and routers are limited.  If you fill them, even with lots of small messages, the packets can be dropped.  Some routers have a buffer size of 1 MB per connection (so if that is connected to router that is the total for everything over that connection)

Comment: Correct. If we use large bufffers, TCP/IP stack will send more packets at hight rate, and intermediate hosts will drop as they don't have large buffers. Actually OP has to measure connection speed and send packets with that rate.

Comment: ... and be very careful to look for micro-bursts.  It is the highest level of buffering which causes drop outs. i.e. you can get drop outs with 0.1% network utilisation if your data is particularly bursty as it is 100% busy 0.1% of the time.